# Makefile for two independent programs sharing the same header

Tags: c, makefile, header

So I have a shared.h file, and a sharedprocess1.c and a sharedprocess2.c file. The .c files share declarations from the header but otherwise they do completely different things. I want to make a Makefile so i can run one OR the other but they both share the same .h file. How can i do this?

Comment: You should show what you've tried already, and show what commands you invoked and what happened that you didn't want.  Just to be clear, typically makefiles don't "run" things.  They compile things.

Comment: Search for "Makefile template" and become enlightened.

Comment: In general, you can't write a makefile to do something, until you know how to do it *without* a makefile.